# Appium iOS code coverage

Tags: ios, code-coverage, appium, appium-ios

I am using Appium for automation test cases in iOS project. I would like to create a report of code coverage. I have gone through appium documentation as well as on internet forums, but didnt find any way.

Is there any way to get it for iOS (Appium)?

Comment: u mean u need logging mechanism?

Comment: I don't know if you are talking about report generated by frameworks or no ? What i know if you are using TestNG framework you can get reports .

Comment: probably here code coverage is not a question associated with appium and that shall not be different from any other way you can find on the Internet

Comment: @kapil Even I too having the same requirement. Have you got any help on this?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do a code coverage because appium doesn't test the actual source code. Appium tests only from the UI level. You might have to manually map the functional test cases and see which all functions it get called when the test is done. But certainly there is no way to figure out like UnitTests with a report to see percent wise code covered report.